# passing parameters from view to controller php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

**In view file**

action="{{ route('uploadfile', ['file_id' => 1]) }}" method="post">

**In route file**

```
Route::post('/uploadfile',['uses'=>'FileController@uploadfile','as'=>'uploadfile']);
```

**In controller**

```
 public function uploadfile($file_id)
{

}
```

**My question is** : how i can get value from view to controller without showing them into url using post method it gives error.

Comment: use form post method to post the values

Comment: basically my view is <form action="{{ route('uploadfile', ['file_id' => 1]) }}" method="post"> @VinodVT

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to pass variable like that. You can submit the value using this method,

**In view file**

```
<form action="{{ route('uploadfile') }}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="file_id" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**In controller**

```
 public function uploadfile(){
    $file_id = Input::get('file_id');
    return $file_id;
}
```

Try this